# Extracting the exposure time from the JPEG header in android

Tags: android, jpeg

I'm doing a camera application and I need to extract the exposure time of the picture that's in the header. I'm transferring the image over network and I need to transmit the exposure time before the actual picture.

Now I know that in some program like irfanview you can extract the exposure time, but I need to do it with Android SDK, so I want to know if it's possible at all or if maybe someone already did this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try ExifInterface (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) ?

Comment: OMG !! I can't believe I haven't seen this before, this is just what I need thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface("test.jpg");
        String exposure = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle IO error
    }
```